# School Management System with Django

Tags: django

Can someone suggest me how to create a Quiz app?.My requirement is when teacher creates a test,the test should be displayed to the student(test should be displayed with the test created teacher name),how to take test and marks should be displayed after test submit.

im a fresher actually,hope I will get my answer.Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you are looking for might be answered by [NBGrader](https://nbgrader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which is a suite of tools for the [Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/) ecosystem that:

- facilitates creating and grading assignments in the Jupyter notebook.
- allows instructors to easily create notebook-based assignments that include both coding exercises and written free-responses.
- then also provides a streamlined interface for quickly grading completed assignments.
- Programming and multiple choice answers can be automatically marked/graded.
- Free form text answers generally need to be manually assessed.